# How do I pass the timeout setting of CTest to test binaries?

Tags: cmake, ctest

When running CTest with `--timeout 120` (or the default timeout), how is that number passed on to the test binary?

I have a C/C++ test binary and it appears that the timeout is neither passed on to the test binary on its command-line, nor its environment variables. Is there a CMake trick that inserts magic commands into `CTestTestfile.cmake` to forward that setting?

Comment: `how is that number passed on to the test binary?` Why would it be passed? It's the timeout for test execution, not an argument.

Comment: Why would it not be passed on in some way? Tests may want to know about it.

Comment: `Test may want to know about it` Exactly - because it affects the test. From my perspective, timeout is irrelevant to the test itself. Test should run under the same environment, no mater if I am in a hurry on my local machine with `--timeout 1` or I'm executing tests on my gitlab-ci/cd pipeline with `--timeout 2000`. Ex. if I buy faster PC, so I'll pass a smaller timeout because of that, should the test be different? It should be the same test, it should test the same things. Test should stay the same, so to `Tests may want to know about it` then I do not see a reason why.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I pass the timeout setting of CTest to test binaries?

You could use environment variables.

> how is that number passed on to the test binary?

It is not, not that I know of.

> Is there a CMake trick that inserts magic

I would just use an environment variable.

```
add_test(... COMMAND wrapper_script.sh the_executable args...)
```

and then in `wrapper_script.sh` (or preferably similar code with a cmake script for portability, TODO):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "$@" --the-timeout "${MY_TIMEOUT:-1500}"
```

and then when `ctest` is run the timeout has to be set and exported to environment variables:

```
export MY_TIMEOUT=200 ; ctest --timeout "$MY_TIMEOUT" ...
```

With such design it could be simpler if the test executable itself would just read the environment variable `MY_TIMEOUT`.